# Is using references in channels a mistake/bad?

Tags: go, channel

Say I have a large list of strings and I want to sort them, beyond the usual sort.Sort and sort.Slice etc I wanted to use more than one core to speed things up. So while reading the large list I add the strings to 2 different slices, strings that start with a-m and n-z (for arguments sake).

Meanwhile I've fired up multiple go routines to read a channel of string slices which will then sort their own sublists. So far, so good, "potentially" parallel processing of the lists so my sort time if effectively halved. Great.  Now my question is how do I get the results back to the main goroutine?

Originally each goroutine had 2 channels, one for incoming unsorted list and the other for sorted list. Yes it works...  but uses SOOO much memory (hey give the volume of data I'm tinkering with for this test, that's probably not unreasonable). But then it dawned on me that by passing a slice on a channel is really just passing a reference, so I don't actually NEED to pass anything back. Not having to put the resulting sorted lists in a channel for the return journey is obviously far less taxing memory wise, but it (to me) smells.

This means I could have one of the goroutines sorting away meanwhile the main goroutine (in theory) could be manipulating the same list. As long as discipline is used this wouldn't be an issue, but is still obviously a concern. Is there a generally accepted best practice within Go to say that references shouldn't be passed as input from one goroutine to another.... but IS acceptable that a goroutine generating reference data can be returned via a channel (since the goroutine would then stop using the reference).

Before anyone says it, yes I know I don't have to pass these in via channels etc but this just the case I was tinkering with and got me thinking.

Long and hand wavy I know. Here's a minimal subset of code showing the above.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func sortWordsList(id int, ch chan []string ) {

    l := <- ch
    sort.Strings(l)
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("big.txt")
    defer file.Close()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("BOOM %s\n", err.Error())
        panic(err)
    }

    // Start reading from the file with a reader.
    reader := bufio.NewReader(file)

    inCh1 := make(chan []string, 1000)
    inCh2 := make(chan []string, 1000)

    go sortWordsList(1, inCh1)
    go sortWordsList(2, inCh2)

    wg.Add(2)

    words1 := []string{}
    words2 := []string{}

    for {
        line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            break
        }

        sp := strings.Split(line, " ")
        for _,w := range sp {
            word := strings.ToLower(w)
            word = strings.TrimSuffix(word, "\n")
            if len(word) > 0 {
                // figure out where to go.
                // arbitrary split.
                if word[0] < 'm' {
                    words1 = append(words1, word)
                } else {
                    words2 = append(words2, word)
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    inCh1 <- words1
    inCh2 <- words2

    close(inCh1)
    close(inCh2)

    wg.Wait()

    // now have sorted words1 and words2 slices.
}
```

Comment: "is using references in channels a mistake/bad?" --- if it solves your problems: then it's good no matter what community says. Make decisions based on your needs, not on what the community thinks you should do.

Comment: It's more about if there is a general best practice for that type of situation. Yes, absolutely it works for me in this contrived situation... but also the next developer to come along and maintain/modify this code mightn't realise that another goroutine is modifying the same list, so BOOM things go up in smoke. Personally I'd use it for a small tool thats for me/small group... but if there is a remote chance of it going further I'd want to try to find an alternative .

Comment: That is what a little thing called „documentation“ is good for. ;) Godoc **and** comment your code accordingly.

Comment: There are no references in Go. So no: you cannot use nonexisting references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with passing pointers, slices, or maps. As long as you synchronize the access to the shared variable, you can pass a pointer and keep on using it in the sending goroutine. For large objects like arrays or large structs, passing a pointer is usually the logical thing to do to avoid expensive copies. Also, avoiding passing pointer means avoiding passing slices and maps, or anything that contains slices, maps, or pointers to other structs.

As you already know, you don't really need channels here, simply start your goroutines after you constructed your slices, and pass the slices directly.

```
go sortWordsList(words1)
go sortWordsList(words2)
```

or:

```
go sort.Strings(words1)
go sort.Strings(words2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info... yes, I know this is a contrived/non-real-world example, but it got me thinking about reference passing in channels in general.

Comment: It would be ideal if the checked answers didn't use the term "references": a lot of beginners read it and start to believe there _are_ references in go, while there is no.